# Android LVL: 'Could not bind to service' again (getApplicationContext() does not help)

Tags: android, android-lvl

- I copied *{android-sdk}\extras\google\play_licensing\sample* , added *{android-sdk}\extras\google\play_licensing\library\src* to the *src* dir of the copied project.
- Modified BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY, set it to one of my keys.
- On the emulator added google account, signed in. It is the account which BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY corresponds to.
- License test response is set to LICENSED
- Tried to change

  ```
  new ServerManagedPolicy(this, ...)
  ```

  to

  ```
  new ServerManagedPolicy(this.getApplicationContext(), ...)
  ```
- Also in `LicenseChecker.checkAccess()` tried to change

  ```
  mContext.bindService()
  ```

  to

  ```
  mContext.getApplicationContext().bindService()
  ```

`.bindService()` still returns false and during bindService() call logcat still reports a warning:

```
Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService }: not found
```

Can someone reference me please a working example of LVL?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. 'Google API' must be utilized instead of 'Android' both for a project and for an emulator avd.